# Using opencpu in production

Tags: javascript, r, mean-stack, ejs, opencpu

It might be a simple question but...
Say I deploy a MEAN application.
I also have opencpu server installed on my machine and also a package with  /inst/www/ directory in it. So my question is,

Do I need to put all the ejs files in /inst/www/ directory in my R package, in order to make my website work?
In online examples I only see that people use ocpu.seturl(), but I cant find any examples about how to use R-package on the server on the same machine.

Comment: You can set a local path i.e. `ocpu.seturl("/ocpu/library/yourpkg/R")`

Comment: @Jeroen thanks, and I must install my package in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` before, I am right? Thanks for the awesome opencpu!

Comment: Yes. You can also install it in some users home library, in that case you need `ocpu.seturl("/ocpu/user/<username>/library/yourpkg/R")`